# How to exchange the normal table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr class="rows">      
        <td>@item.CourseName</td>
        <td>@item.ClassName</td>
        <td>@item.StuName</td>
        <td>@item.Age</td> 
        <td>@item.Scores</td>
        <td>           
            @Html.ActionLink("edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
            <a id="@item.ID" onclick="deletescore(@item.ID)">delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to change the table using jquery? First I receive a list type model, and foreach the model and add them to different row as the upside, but now I want to change it using jQuery.
Here is what I have tried to do:

Javascript:

```js
function makeTable(container, data)
 {
        var table = $("<table/>").addClass('TableMaker');

 function thmaker ()
{
            //table head
            var row = $("<tr/>")
            var thdata = ["course", "class", "name","age","scores","option"]               
            row.append($("<th/>").text（thdata）)


 }
        $.each(data, function (rowIndex, r)
 {
            var row = $("<tr/>")
            $.each(r, function (colIndex, c) {
                row.append($("<td/>").text(c));
                row.append($("<td/>").text(—how to add here-))
            });
            table.append(row);
        });
        return container.append(table);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () 
    { $(".tablemaker").show(function()
{
        var data = @Model.ToArray(); 
//here the data seem not showing , the original model is list type
        var ScoreTable = makeTable($(document.body), data);
    });
    });
```

Comment: 1. And what do you want to change exactly? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. You should provide rendered HTML.

Comment: i have found a similar question on this website .

Comment: <table>
    <tr style="display:block">
        <td id="someid">Test</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>      ！！！change to jquery like this ！！！                                                    var newtr = "<tr style='display:none'><td id='someid'></td><td></td></tr>"
$("td#someid").parent().replacewith(newtr);

Comment: and how can i change the table to jquery and  still have the value. in my code ,i bind the value of every td with the data send form server side .hope for your answer.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26523866/edit). Don't put HTML or code in a comment.

Comment: I think you should show us the output of `@Model.ToArray();`, maybe make a fiddle with the model data printed out.